# First time doing Ajax with WP, how to do it?

Tags: ajax

I have been trying to work this out from various posts over the years but just can't seem to get it to work as I am not a Jquery guru and I am struggling to get my head around it.

My html:

```
<select id="shoe-kids" class="form-control hide-select">
 <option value="" selected>Select Sub-category</option>
 <option value="trainers-kids-shoes">Trainers</option>
</select>
```

My ajax (in my js file)

```
$('#shoes-kids').on('change', function(){
  $.ajax({
   url:"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
   type:'POST',
   data:'action=',
   success:function(results) {
    $("#product-results").append(results);
   }
  });
 });
```

Functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-filter2', 'tsf_load_products' );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_load-filter2', 'tsf_load_products' );
 function tsf_load_products () {

  $product_args = array (
   'post_type' => 'shoes',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'order' => 'DESC',
   'tax_query' => array(
    array(
     'taxonomy' => 'tsf_category',
     'field'    => 'slug',
     'terms'    => 'trainers-kids-shoes',
     'operator' => 'IN'
    )
   ),
  );
  $product_query = new WP_Query( $product_args );
  while ( $product_query->have_posts() ) {
     $product_query->the_post();
   echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();

 }
```

I know how it will work in my head but I am struggling to get it all to work in practise, the bits I am struggling with are:

1) Adding the data to the ajax call (what do I need to put in there)

2) How to add the information to the localise script function (for my js file)

3) Spitting the result into the site

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably the go to article of the official documentation on this is »[AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)« - you pretty much can ignore the plug-in part in the header, as it applies to themes too. Additionally take a look at the section »[jQuery noConflict Wrappers](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)« on the `wp_enqueue_script()` documentation page.

Comment: You have used category to send data from ajax but you have not used it. To access that use $_POST['category'] and make sure #shoe-kids id is present..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#shoes-kids').on('change', function(){
$.post('<?php echo admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" ); ?>',  {
          first_name: ""+ $("#first_name").val(), //sending first name
          last_name: ""+ $("#last_name").val(), //sending last name
      action : 'your_ajax_hook'
        },  function(data,status){
            if(status=="success")
        {
         $("#product-results").append(data);
        }
        else
        {
        alert('Failed');
        }
    });
 });
```

i.e:-

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_your_ajax_hook', 'your_function_name' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_your_ajax_hook', 'your_function_name'  );
```

In above I have send first_name and last_name as a post data you can sent more by just putting ',' as a separator

Comment: I have done all that (after reading the plugin link above) but still can't get anything to fire (no failed alert etc)

My pastebin for all the functions.php stuff is http://pastebin.com/L6bF2gZT